# Derivation of filter tables

Tags: analog, filter

Could someone please point me in the right direction for finding derivations showing how normalised filter table values come about?  What should I be searching for to find the derivations?

I've included an example of the type of table that I'm talking about.
[image: FilterTable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these classic tables come from the work of [Wilhelm Cauer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Cauer) on [network synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_synthesis). Such filters are known as Cauer Networks or Cauer Ladders as a result of this work. There is also the Cauer filter which is a special case of such a network. A good book on circuit theory should cover some of this and, if I remember correctly, it involves long division of Laplace polynomials (generalized continued fractions) - not for the faint hearted!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Would you by any chance be able to recommend an appropriate book?